# Is it possible to Update the AuraDefinationBundle developerName

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I have wrongly named one component,now i would like to change the developer name i think we cannot do from developer console, i tried with back end logic with execute anonymous code

```
AuraDefinitionBundle auraDfntionBundle = [Select Id,DeveloperName from AuraDefinitionBundle where DeveloperName like '%test%' limit 1];
System.debug(auraDfntionBundle);
auraDfntionBundle.DeveloperName = 'New Test';
update(auraDfntionBundle);
```

i am getting the following error

```
DML not allowed on AuraDefinitionBundle
```

but as per in document , this object type has update support call, please let me know if am missing anything here.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_auradefinitionbundle.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document link you have is of SOAP API .This means you will need to use workbench or dataloader to load the records and perform update via the SOAP API .The object is not available via apex interface .

Answer (score 0):

Delete the component from dev console then create it again with the good name :)

Comment: yes thought of it but just want to try this way also(as it has API).